# How to verify whether an instance of CharSequence is a sequence of Unicode scalar values?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-16, charsequence, surrogate-pairs

I have an instance of `java.lang.CharSequence`. I need to determine whether this instance is a sequence of [Unicode scalar values](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value) (that is, whether the instance is in UTF-16 encoding form). Despite the assurances of `java.lang.String`, a Java string is not necessarily in UTF-16 encoding form (at least not according to the latest [Unicode specification](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0), currently 6.2), since it may contain isolated [surrogate code units](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#surrogate_code_point). (A Java string is, however, a [Unicode 16-bit string](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_string).)

There are several obvious ways in which to go about this, including:

1. Iterate over the [code points](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#codePointAt%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29) of the sequence, explicitly validating each as a Unicode scalar value.
2. Use a regular expression to search for isolated surrogate code points.
3. Pipe the character sequence through a [character-set encoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) that [reports encoding errors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html#REPORT).

It seems as though something like this should already exist as a library function, however. I just can't find it in the standard API. Am I missing it, or do I need to implement it?

Comment: There is a [isValidCodepoint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isValidCodePoint%28int%29) function. All it needs is some extra filter to remove surrogates.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes The isValidCodePoint function determines whether an int value falls within the range of Unicode code points. However, the range of Unicode scalar values is a restriction on the range of Unicode code points.

Comment: Well, my point is that isValidCodepoint is the best you have. I believe you will have to get this validation from an external library (like ICU) or do it yourself.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Hmm, the ICUJ libraries are a good idea, if a bit heavy. I might need them for some other stuff, though, so worth a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this func

```
static boolean isValidUTF16(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLowSurrogate(s.charAt(i)) && (i == 0 || !Character.isHighSurrogate(s.charAt(i - 1)))
                || Character.isHighSurrogate(s.charAt(i)) && (i == s.length() -1 || !Character.isLowSurrogate(s.charAt(i + 1)))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

here's a test

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(isValidUTF16("\uDC00\uDBFF"));
    System.out.println(isValidUTF16("\uDBFF\uDC00"));
}
```

Comment: That'll work. It can be done a bit more efficiently by iterating over code points rather than characters, but that's effectively one of the possible implementations I listed in the question. I think you have an extra condition at the end, though, since `i` can never equal `s.length()`.

Comment: thanks 'for extra condition', fixed. This was because of refactoring and long lines length in the code, didnt notice it.